# Make Win + ↓ minimize the current window

Tags: gala, microsoft-windows

When using Windows (10) I can press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> to minimize the current window.

In elementary OS freya I cannot do it and instead it opens the virtual desktops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go into System Settings --> Keyboard, you should be able to change the shortcut for minimizing the current window. If you change it to a shortcut that's already in use (such as <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>), the old shortcut will be removed and your new shortcut will replace it.